# XPath for "Onclick" attribute

Tags: xpath, onclick, buttonclick

I have to perform a click event on one of the option in a drop down menu on a web page, here is my absolute path for the element.

Absolute Path:-

[image]

And I have tried Xpath to find the element:-

[image]

All the combination of Xpaths that I tried are not working.
Please do suggest me if you have any solution for the same?

Many Thanks,
Shruti

Answer (score 0):

Try with these Xpaths:

`//a[@data-original-title='Excel']`

`//a[@alt='Excel']`

`//a[text()='Excel']`